# Send a new email using GTLGmail Class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, gmail-api

I am working on the gmail app and I want to send a new email with.

I know that we have to make the query as following :-

```
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmailqueryForUsersMessagesSendWithUploadParameters:nil];
query.message = gtlGmailMessage; //parent message
[self.service executeQuery:query
              delegate:self
     didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResult:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

But I am unable to understand how to make the gtlGmailMessage message to be passed in query.

i.e

```
 GTLGmailMessage *gtlGmailMessage = [[GTLGmailMessage alloc] init];
```

Can any one tell be where to enter payload data , how to set to and from field.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41714135/2050181) how i manage to send only the message as a raw data:

and [google-api-objectivec-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) is deprecated it has been replaced by [google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest)

```
NSString *messageString =                              @"From: \"From Email USer Name\" <fromEmail>\r\n";
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"To: \"To Email User Name\" <ToEmail>\r\n"];
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"Subject: New stuff\r\n"];
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n"];
messageString = [messageString stringByAppendingString:@"Hello my friend, \n can you please call me when have free time. \nMark."];

NSData *data = [messageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64Encoded = GTLREncodeWebSafeBase64(data);


GTLRGmail_Message *message = [[GTLRGmail_Message alloc] init];

message.raw = base64Encoded;

GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend *query = [GTLRGmailQuery_UsersMessagesSend queryWithObject:message userId:@"myEmailAddress" uploadParameters:nil];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket * _Nonnull callbackTicket, id  _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable callbackError) {
      NSLog(@"%@",callbackError);
 }];
```